# 2-norm of a canonical Jordan form and spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $J$ be a canonical Jordan form (real or complex). Is it true that the $2$-norm of $J$ is equal to its spectral radius?

Comment: Notice that the spectral radius is nothing but the maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues. Just play with the identity matrix.

Comment: Could you please   provide more details

Comment: What you mean by $2$-norm?

Comment: The $2$-norm of a matrix $A$ is by definition $$\left\Vert A\right\Vert=\underset{\mid x\mid_2=1}{\sup}\mid Ax\mid_2$$, where$\mid .\mid_2$ is the euclidian norm.

Comment: Even for the real case? could you indicate me a suitable reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $J=\bigoplus_{i=1}^kJ_i$, where $J_i$ is an elementary Jordan block of the dimension $n_i$ ($\sum_{i=1}^k=n$) corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{C}$. Then
$$
\rho(J)=\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}|\lambda_i|, \quad \text{and}\quad
\|J\|_2=\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}\|J_i\|_2,
$$
so the insight related to whether or not this is true can be obtained by examining the validity of the statement for elementary Jordan blocks.

For an elementary Jordan block $J_i\in\mathbb{C}^{n_i\times n_i}$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{C}$, we have:

> $$\rho(J_i)=\|J_i\|_2 \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n_i=1.$$

**Proof:** It is easy to see that $\rho(J_i)=\|J_i\|_2$ if $n_i=1$.
Now assume that $n_i\geq 2$.
Consider the diagonal entry $(n_i,n_i)$ of the matrix $J_i^*J_i$, which is equal to $|\lambda_i|^2+1$. Since the diagonal entries of an HPD matrix bound from below its spectral radius, it follows that
$$
\|J_i\|_2^2=\rho(J_i^*J_i)\geq|\lambda_i|^2+1>|\lambda_i|^2=\rho^2(J_i).
$$

**Some sufficient conditions for $\rho(J)=\|J\|_2$:**

- Obviously, if $J$ is diagonal then $\rho(J)=\|J\|_2$.
- From the Gershgorin theorem applied on $J_i^*J_i$, one can see that
  $$\tag{$*$}
  |\lambda_i|\leq\|J_i\|_2\leq|\lambda_i|+1.
  $$
  Assume that $\rho(J)=|\lambda_j|$ for some $1\leq j\leq k$ and let $n_j=1$. If $|\lambda_i|+1\leq|\lambda_j|=\rho(J)$ for all $i\neq j$ (this is a sufficient condition for $\|J_i\|_2\leq|\lambda_j|$), then $\rho(J)=\|J\|_2$. Actually, the condition that $\|J_i\|_2\leq|\lambda_j|$ for all $i\neq j$ might be also a necessary condition.

Note that the bounds in ($*$) are sharp. The lower bound is attained for $n_i=1$ while the upper bound is attained asymptotically for $n_i\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Doesn't my example below disprove $\|J\|_2\leq\sqrt{|\lambda|^2+1}$?

Comment: Yes it does indeed.

Comment: Is there a tighter upper bound (as a function of $|\lambda_i|$) for $\|J\|_2$ in ($\star$)? Now I have that $|\lambda_i|<1$ for any $i$. Is it possible to prove $\|J^k\| \leq \rho^k$ for some $\rho <1$?

Comment: @ShiJames Not really, if $|\lambda|<1$ then $\|J^k\|_2$ has always a stage where $\|J^k\|_2>1$ for all $k$ below some $K\geq 1$ (unless $n=1$). You can use the formula $|\lambda|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|J^k\|^{\frac{1}{k}}$ to obtain an asymptotic bound. Namely you can show that for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $\|J^k\|_2\leq (|\lambda|+\epsilon)^k$ starting from some other $K=K(\epsilon)$. I'm not aware of a better bound though (which does not mean it does not exist of course).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **no**. Consider the following Jordan cell
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1,$ spectral radius is $\rho(A)=\max_{k=1,2}|\lambda_k|=1,$ spectral norm is
$$
\|A\|_2 = \max\frac{|Ax|_2}{|x|_2} \geq \frac{\left| A e \right|_2}{|e|_2} = \frac{\left|\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right|_2}{\left|\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right|_2} = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2.5}\approx 1.58,
$$
where $e=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$ 
The actual norm is even larger, try to find it yourself.

Comment: Just we can play with the vector $e_2=(0,1)$. Notice that $\|e_2\|_2=1$ and $Ae_2=(1,1)$. Hence $\frac{\|Ae_2\|_2}{\|e_2\|_2}=\sqrt{2}>1$.

Comment: Computations are easier if you take $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix} $. Then the spectral radius is zero and the norm is one.